# XML Menu Background Memory Issues

Tags: android, xml, out-of-memory

I'm developing an android game. I use xml files to create 2 menus. The menus work fine when the have the same background, but when they have different backgrounds the program crashes with an OutOfMemoryError.

Here is what the two xml files look like:

File 1:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background">

                Bunch of TextViews
```

File 2 is exactly the same except the background is @drawable/background2

The LogCat error I get is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(534): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread
E/AndroidRuntime(534): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
```

I'm not really sure how this error relates to me changing the background image, and the problem is not related to the size of the background images that I am using. I tried having one background image of 800KB and there was no problem, but when I try two different background images of around 150KB I get an error.

I have an activity that creates the menu:

```
 public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_new);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is the `GLThread` the appropriate one to be doing what you are doing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have an activity that creates the menu:
` public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main_new); `

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the garbage collector. it

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        System.gc();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is not related to the size of the background images that I am using.

Actually, it is, although with a different meaning of *size*. The file size doesn't matter at runtime, because internally Android loads all images as `Bitmap`s in an `ARGB_8888` format. That means that every pixel is represented by 4 bytes and that the *visual size* (image dimensions/resolution) determines the memory required to display the image. For example, an 800 x 480 px image will require 800 * 480 * 4 = 1536000 bytes at runtime, or roughly 1,5 MB.

That being said, it should be clear why it is important to provide assets for the different density buckets Android specifies. If you haven't read through the ["Supporting Multiple Screens" guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), I highly recommend doing so. Providing correctly sized assets can potentially signficantly improve memory usage, although it does usually come at the cost of a larger apk.

Furthermore, you have several more options. For example, if the content of the background images allows it, convert them into [9-patches](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html). You can also experiment with loading the images in the (deprecated for quality reasons) `ARGB_4444` format, which will halve the memory usage compared to `ARGB_8888`.

Finally, depending on your implementation specifics, you may be able to improve memory usage at runtime by manually releasing resources, e.g. by calling `recycle()` on `Bitmap` objects. Although the Dalvik VM will also take care of garbage collecting unreferenced resources, it can take a couple of cycles before that actually happens. Explicitly releasing resources sometimes helps and is for example common practice if you only load `Bitmap`s to pass them on to the OpenGL pipeline as texture. Also, in case you use OpenGL textures, don't forget to call `gl.glDeleteTextures(...)` to release memory containing textures you don't need anymore.

Comment: Thanks, but I feel there is something that I am still not understanding. I used to have a single 800X480 px background, which works. I just tried having two 400X240 px backgrounds, and that isn't working. What am I not understanding? 
again, I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: That's indeed surprising. Are the actual image assets 400 x 240 pixels, or do you scale the image programmatically? In the latter case I wouldn't be surprised If you'd still encounter issues. Perhaps you could share some of your relevant code?